# How can i handle a null value returned from a lambda selection?

Tags: c#, lambda

I am using the following lambda selection

```
if (users.Any(x => x.userId.ToString() == id))
{
     var user = _users.First(x => x.userId.ToString() == id);
    _users.Remove(user);
}
//use entitybase to setup the user and its id.i have left that bit out 
_users.Add(user)
```

There are no values in the users list that match id so the line

```
users.Any(x => x.userId.ToString() == id  // gives a "Object reference exception"
```

Is there a selection in lambda i can use that takes care of nulls.

Comment: Try `.FirstOrDefault(...); if ( user != null ) _users.Remove(user);`. [Linq 1](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/linq/index.htm) | [Linq 2](https://www.webtrainingroom.com/linq) | [C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp)

Comment: Unrelated: I'd suggest you parse `id` to whatever type `userId` is instead of `toString()`.

Comment: try `users.Any(x => x!= null && x.userId.ToString() == id);`. It is giving exception becaause there  is some value in the list whic is `null`

Comment: Indeed, also; `x != null && x.userId != null && x.userId.ToString() == id`

Comment: @OlivierRogier yes, you are right

Comment: `_users.Add(user)` <-- `user` is actually out of scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest to instead of `.ToString()`, parse `id` to the type `userId` is.

Then:

```
// this is compeletely unneccessary
//if (users.Any(x => x.userId.ToString() == id))
//{
     // vv this assumes that if x is not null, property `userId` is required, so cannot be null
     var user = _users.FirstOrDefault(x => !(x is null) && x.userId == id);
     if(!(user is null)) // C# 9 : if( user is not null )
     {
         _users.Remove(user);
     }
//}
```

Alternative Linq:

`var user = _users.Where(x => !(x is null)).FirstOrDefault(x => x.userId ==id);`

Not sure which one would perform better. I'd probably benchmark this.